# CN1 Simulator Hot Reload in Eclipse intended behavior

Tags: codenameone, simulator

I am using Codename One with my preferred editor, Eclipse. My platform is Arch Linux and the code base is a Maven Project from the "Initializr".

Whenever I make changes in CSS, the running simulator shows them immediately, but when I alter java code, the changes do not become instantly visible.

To see the changes, I have to save the java file in Eclipse, but then the simulator closes and opens again, a thing that I hoped I could avoid.

From the instructions found [here](https://www.codenameone.com/codename-one-simulator.html) and [here](https://shannah.github.io/cn1-maven-archetypes/cn1app-archetype-tutorial/getting-started.html#running), I understood that there should be a Hot-Reload-Button or mechanism like " “Apply Code Changes” somewhere, but I couldn't find any.

Am I missing something, or is the closing and automatically reopening of the simulator intended? The Hot-Reload option in the simulator ist activated.

Comment: This is mostly about CSS changes which should happen immediately. You can use look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/ysvw3u/undocumented_hotswap_feature/) for some of the more elaborate options.